# QAbstractItemModel index design

Tags: c++, qt5

Question: When implementing a derived QAbstractItemModel that represent a tree structure, what are good solutions for handling QModelIndex that map to custom objects?

In a old project a TreeItem class (similar to Simple Tree Model Example) was used to represent the tree structure. In that case it worked well because all the nodes had the same type. We basically casted the QModelIndex internalPointer to a TreeItem.

In a new project we are faced with a tree structure with multiple types with no relation between the types.

```
struct X
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  double d;
};

struct y
{
  QString e;
  double f;
};

struct z
{
  QString    g;
  QVector<x> h;
  QVector<y> i;
};
```

So using TreeItem does not appear to work aswell. We can cast the CModelIndex internalPointer to a TreeItem class which gives us the hierarchy info but not a specific type of that instance. We could do something like this

```
class x : public TreeNode {}
class y : public TreeNode {}
class z : public TreeNode {}
```

which would give use the specialized class but it would require another casting which is not ideal.

Another approach would be to use the pointer of the struct(s) in QModelIndex internalPointer to identify a "tree node". Not a big fan of using void* as an identifier, this seems like a low level solution but should work. Does feel a bit high maintenance-ish and as easy to understand.